# Workbox cache URLs from message event

Tags: javascript, service-worker, workbox

I try to add some `routes` in cache using message event.

On every page, there are several on dynamic that I would like to keep in cache. For this, i send an array of URL to my Service Worker on document load :

```
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
  if (serviceWorker.isServiceWorkerSupported()) {
    serviceWorker.register();

   if (typeof PRECACHE_ROUTES !== 'undefined') {
      serviceWorker.sendPreCacheRoutesToSW(PRECACHE_ROUTES);
    }
  }
});
```

But, with this method, if user have no network, the `StaleWhileRevalidate` same not work, you can see an example :

```
registerRoute(
  '/',
  new StaleWhileRevalidate({
    cacheName: 'routes', // Work on offline
    plugins,
  }),
);

self.addEventListener('message', event => {
  if (event.data && event.data.type === 'PRECACHE_ROUTES') {
    event.data.routes.forEach(route => {
      registerRoute(
        route,
        new StaleWhileRevalidate({
          cacheName: 'routes', // Not work on offline
        }),
      );
    });

    event.waitUntil(
      caches.open('routes').then(cache => cache.addAll(event.data.routes)),
    );
  }
});
```

All urls are well cached, but do not seem to be taken into account offline.

Anyone can help me ?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest following [this recipe](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/modules/workbox-window#example-cache-urls) using `workbox-window` and `workbox-routing` to accomplish that:

```js
// From within your web page, using workbox-window:
const wb = new Workbox('/sw.js');

wb.addEventListener('activated', (event) => {
  // Get the current page URL + all resources the page loaded.
  // Replace with a list of URLs obtained elsewhere, as needed.
  const urlsToCache = [
    location.href,
    ...performance.getEntriesByType('resource').map((r) => r.name),
  ];
  // Send that list of URLs to your router in the service worker.
  wb.messageSW({
    type: 'CACHE_URLS',
    payload: {urlsToCache},
  });
});

// Register the service worker after event listeners have been added.
wb.register();
```

This will automatically apply the routes defined in your service worker to the URLs you provide in the `payload`.

Dynamically setting up routes for those URLs inside of your `message` event isn't going to give you the behavior you're after, as you've found.

Comment: Hello Jeff ! Thank you for URL and tips. But, on service-worker side, i've not really understand how i save the URls on cache ?

Comment: There's code in `workbox-routing` to automatically apply the route matching incoming URLs sent via a `CACHE_URLS` message: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/workbox/blob/72335abe601312b2757ff64fcb7b2aa6af23180a/packages/workbox-routing/src/Router.ts#L88-L109